# uninitialized constant PostsController

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am getting the error that my PostsController isn't initialized.

Here is my routes.rb file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  root to: 'posts#index'

  scope module: 'blog' do
    get 'about' => 'pages#about', as: :about
    get 'contact' => 'pages#contact', as: :contact
    resources :posts 
  end 
end
```

The filename for my posts controller is: posts_controller.rb

The path is app/controller/blog/posts_controller.rb

Here's an excerpt of the posts_controller.rb file:

```
module Blog
  class PostsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your PostsController is defined in Blog module so the route should be

```
root to: "blog/posts#index"
```

Comment: Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `PostsController`, you have a namespaced `Blog::PostsController`.

So,

```
`root to 'posts#index'`
```

is trying to route to a non-existent `PostsController` and so you're getting the (accurate) error.

Try

```
root to: 'blog/posts#index'
```

Comment: Thanks for your time!

Comment: Sure thing. Did you get it fixed? Did one of these answers help?

Comment: Sorry, for the delay; yes, I did get it fixed by re-coding the whole thing.  I think there's a glitch in Rails.